# Dynamically setting host for Spring AMQP and RabbitMQ on Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

i have a problem, i do not know how to set the host dynamically and doing RPC operation on different host

Here is the situation

I have a multiple RabbitMQ running on different servers and networks (i.e 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.2.0/24).

The behavior would be i have a list of IP address which i will perform an RPC with. 
So, for each entry in the ip address list, i want to perform a `convertSendAndReceive` and process the reply and so on.

Tried some codes in documentation but it seems it does not work even the invalid address (addresses that don't have a valid RabbitMQ running, or is not event existing on the network, for example 1.1.1.1) gets received by a valid RabbitMQ (running on 192.168.1.1 for example)

**Note: I can successfully perform RPC call on correct address, however, i can also successfully perform RPC call on invalid address which im not suppose to**

Anyone has any idea about this?

Here is my source

**TaskSchedulerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class TaskSchedulerConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private IpAddressRepo ipAddressRepo;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteProcedureService remote;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString  = "5000", initialDelay = 2000)
    public void scheduledTask() {
        ipAddressRepo.findAll().stream()
              .forEach(ipaddress -> {
                boolean status = false;
                try {
                    remote.setIpAddress(ipaddress);
                    remote.doSomeRPC();                 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.debug("Unable to Connect to licenser server: {}", license.getIpaddress());
                    logger.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
                } 
              });

    }

}
```

**RemoteProcedureService.java**

```
@Service
public class RemoteProcedureService {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private DirectExchange exchange;


    public boolean doSomeRPC() throws JsonProcessingException {

        //I passed this.factory.getHost() so that i will know if only the valid ip address will be received by the other side
        //at this point, other side receives invalid ipaddress which supposedly will not be receive by the oher side
        boolean response = (Boolean) template.convertSendAndReceive(exchange.getName(), "rpc", this.factory.getHost());
        return response;
    }

    public void setIpAddress(String host) {
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setCloseTimeout(prop.getRabbitMQCloseConnectTimeout());
        factory.setPort(prop.getRabbitMQPort());
        factory.setUsername(prop.getRabbitMQUsername());
        factory.setPassword(prop.getRabbitMQPassword());
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);

    }

}
```

AmqpConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class AmqpConfiguration {
    public static final String topicExchangeName = "testExchange";

    public static final String queueName = "rpc";

    @Autowired
    private LicenseVisualizationProperties prop;

//Commented this out since this will only be assigne once
//i need to achieve to set it dynamically in order to send to different hosts
//so put it in RemoteProcedureService.java, but it never worked
//    @Bean
//    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
//        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
//        connectionFactory.setCloseTimeout(prop.getRabbitMQCloseConnectTimeout());
//        connectionFactory.setPort(prop.getRabbitMQPort());
//        connectionFactory.setUsername(prop.getRabbitMQUsername());
//        connectionFactory.setPassword(prop.getRabbitMQPassword());
//        return connectionFactory;
//    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exhange() {
        return new DirectExchange(topicExchangeName);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 1**

It seems that, during the loop, when an valid ip is set in the `CachingConnectionFactory` succeeding ip addressing loop, regardliess if valid or invalid, gets received by the first valid ip set in `CachingConnectionFactory`

**UPDATE 2**

I found out that once it can establish a successfully connection, it will not create a new connection. How do you force `RabbitTemplate` to establish a new connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather strange use case and won't perform very well; you would be better to have a pool of connection factories and templates.

However, to answer your question:

Call `resetConnection()` to close the connection.

Comment: Yep just found out also `ResetConnection`. Was thinking of that but my list of ip address is dynamic. can't imagine how to perform connection factories where my list of ip address is ever changing